# SQL-Server: Return fields where COUNT(*) is greater or equal to 3

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get results only for those `COUNT` that is >= 3

```
SELECT CustomerNBene.Company, ContractLog.userID
       , CONVERT (varchar(10) ,ContractLog.date, 103) as [date]
       , CONVERT (varchar(10), ContractLog.LValueDate, 103) as LValueDate
       , Payable.ContractNo
       , Payable.bank
       , Payable.currency
       , Payable.Amount
       , (
          SELECT Count(*)
          FROM DimDate
          WHERE DimDate.[Date] BETWEEN CONVERT (varchar(10) ,ContractLog.[date], 112) 
          AND CONVERT (varchar(10), ContractLog.LValueDate, 112) AND DimDate.isweekEND = 0
        ) as Payable
FROM CustomerNBene, ContractLog, Payable
WHERE ContractLog.contractNo = Payable.ContractNo
AND ContractLog.LConStatus = 'VAL'
AND CustomerNBene.ConNo = ContractLog.contractNo
AND CustomerNBene.CustID != '01'
AND (Payable.Confirmed is NULL or Payable.Confirmed = 'N')
ORDER BY Payable desc, bank
```

When I add `AND Payable >= 3`, I get "Invalid Column Name"

How do I go about doing it?

Comment: Payable here is a alias of column for select statement, so you can not put it in the WHERE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use a temptable , insert the result set of your query above in temptable , then apply the filter in temp table.

Try this..

```
 SELECT CustomerNBene.Company, ContractLog.userID
       , CONVERT (varchar(10) ,ContractLog.date, 103) as [date]
       , CONVERT (varchar(10), ContractLog.LValueDate, 103) as LValueDate
       , Payable.ContractNo
       , Payable.bank
       , Payable.currency
       , Payable.Amount
       , (
          SELECT Count(*)
          FROM DimDate
          WHERE DimDate.[Date] BETWEEN CONVERT (varchar(10) ,ContractLog.[date], 112) 
          AND CONVERT (varchar(10), ContractLog.LValueDate, 112) AND DimDate.isweekEND = 0
        ) as Payable
INTO #TempTable -->> Insert into temp table
FROM CustomerNBene, ContractLog, Payable
WHERE ContractLog.contractNo = Payable.ContractNo
AND ContractLog.LConStatus = 'VAL'
AND CustomerNBene.ConNo = ContractLog.contractNo
AND CustomerNBene.CustID != '01'
AND (Payable.Confirmed is NULL or Payable.Confirmed = 'N')
ORDER BY Payable desc, bank

-->> now apply the filtering in temp table
SELECT Company, userID, date, LValueDate, ContractNo, bank, currency, Amount, Payable
FROM #TempTable
GROUP BY Company, userID, date, LValueDate, ContractNo, bank, currency, Amount, Payable
HAVING COUNT([Payable]) >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to know logical order in which statements in queries execute,you can download the poster from the below link and follow numbers to see which operator executes next

http://tsql.solidq.com/books/insidetsql2008/Logical%20Query%20Processing%20Poster.pdf

in simple terms

below query wont work

```
select name,sum(id) as summ
from test
where summ=10
```

you can wrap it  in a cte.CTE is a disposbale view which is not materialized in DB,but will be valid for scope of single execution

```
;with cte
as
(
select name,sum(id) as summ
from test
where summ=10
)
select * from cte where summ=10
```